# Controlling 2 computers, 1 screen, 1 keyboard and 1 mouse

Tags: remote-control

I have 2 computers - Mac and Windows, and I want to use only 1 screen, 1 mouse and 1 keyboard.
I've heard about application named Synergy but I think it only for 2 screens.

Any 1 know how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try http://superuser.com

Comment: this has been answered many times on http://superuser.com try there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to buy a KVM system. It's a hardware device that is specifically designed for this purpose. 1 Keyboard / Video Mouse to many computers.